# How to use Enter press on keyboard to login into the website?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have source code in my application, but when users login they need to click onto Login button.
They do not have option to use Enter press on keyboard.

[Sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XPbs.png)

Comment: Hi Sunny, while it is fine to link to external sources, this is a case where you should include a snipet of your source in your question. Details on how to format your code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
function Onpress(e){
  let pressedkey=(window.event)?event.charCode:e.which;
  if(pressedkey == 13){
    Submitform();
    return true;
  }
}
```

And add onkeypress event into submit button like

```
Onkeypress="return Onpress(event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this

```
$('input,textarea').on('keyup keypress', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```